# Selenium(python) webdriver authorization using default firefox profile on any PC

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium I need to log in to the site with the current profile.
I need the script to work for any *random.default*  profile.
Profile has a random name *random.default* for this I use `os.listdir ()`. But apparently something is wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
default_username = os.getlogin()
ffprofile = os.listdir('C:/users/'+default_username+'/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/')
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/users/'+default_username+'/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/'+ffprofile)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

received error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-1fd6227ccf4f> in <module>()
      4 default_username = os.getlogin()
      5 ffprofile = os.listdir('C:/users/'+default_username+'/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/')
----> 6 fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/users/'+default_username+'/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/'+ffprofile)
      7 driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
      8 driver.get("http://google.com")

TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: Please update your post with exactly what you've found to be wrong, or what you *think* is wrong. Provide some of your own analysis to give others an idea of what may be wrong your code. We're here to *help you*--not to do the work for you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the error indicated.

Comment: What line is the error on? That should help identify what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as indicated by the `TypeError`, is that `os.listdir()` returns a `list`, not a `str`. So when you're trying to append `ffprofile` to the string in your call to `webdriver.FirefoxProfile()`, the `TypeError` is thrown. I'm not sure what your exact use-case is, but this should help you get it working without the error.